# How to have readable Firebase Crashlytics crash reports for Flutter apps?

Tags: firebase, flutter, crashlytics, flutter-ios, flutter-android

I have added Firebase Crashyltics in my Flutter app to crash some crashes that my users have.

I get those reports in dashboard, but they are not giving my any valuable information.

I can not see at which file in my code crash happened, since as you can see in the screenshot they are telling me that crash happened in some plugin, but that is not palace of the crash.

How I can improve this to make it more readable with correct information?

[image]

Comment: For this test, are you calling "FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.crash();" ? have you tried causing a different crash in the app? What version of Crashlytics are you using?

Comment: Unrelated, as you deleted your JUnit / mocking question too quickly: A) learn about parameterized tests. Or at least put your test strings into an array. Every time you start naming variables x1, x2, x3 ... you are doing something wrong (you should be using lists + loops instead). Then: understand that using PowerMock is MOST often ... an indication that you wrote HARD TO TEST code. The solution isnt to use the big powermock hammer. The real solution is to improve your production code to make it EASY to test.